Copy tables across servers PostgresSQL
I'm currently working on a database migration from DB2 to PostgreSQL (v15). One of our requirements is to copy tables on demand across different PostgreSQL servers. We're encountering a performance issue with a particularly large table (approximately 250GB with almost 500 million rows). The time to copy this table in PostgreSQL is 4-5 times longer compared to DB2.
In DB2, we use the following approach:
declare table cursor ... for select * from remote_schema.table and then
and then:
load from table of cursor of messages replace into local_schema.table
PostgreSQL Approaches Tried
With PostgreSQL, we’ve tried a couple of different options:
Using subprocess with multithreaded psql commands (see the full script below):
Using psycopg:

with psycopg.connect(dsn_src) as conn1, psycopg.connect(dsn_tgt) as conn2:
    with conn1.cursor().copy("COPY src TO STDOUT (FORMAT BINARY)") as copy1:
        with conn2.cursor().copy("COPY tgt FROM STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)") as copy2:
            for data in copy1:
                copy2.write(data)

We’ve also tried dropping indexes and constraints before the load, but recreating them afterward took more time than just loading the table as-is.
Server Specifications
Here's the relevant CPU and memory information for the server:
Architecture:          x86_64

CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit

Byte Order:            Little Endian

CPU(s):                8

On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7

Thread(s) per core:    1

Core(s) per socket:    1

Socket(s):             8

NUMA node(s):          1

Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel

CPU family:            6

Model:                 63

Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-4640 v3 @ 1.90GHz

Stepping:              2

CPU MHz:               1899.998

BogoMIPS:              3799.99

Hypervisor vendor:     VMware

Virtualization type:   full

L1d cache:             32K

L1i cache:             32K

L2 cache:              256K

L3 cache:              30720K

NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available

Mem:            125           4           3          36         118          84

Swap:            15           0          15`



-----------------

Current Best Performing Script
Below is the full version of the script that had the best performance, though it is still 5 times slower than DB2 on the same server:

import subprocess
import logging
import threading
import os
import datetime
import sys
import math
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import concurrent.futures

def create_pgpass_file(host, port, database, user, password):
    try:
        pgpass_content = f"{host}:{port}:{database}:{user}:{password}"
        pgpass_path = os.path.expanduser("~/.pgpass")
        with open(pgpass_path, "w") as pgpass_file:
            pgpass_file.write(pgpass_content)
        os.chmod(pgpass_path, 0o600)  # Definir permissões para 600

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error creating .pgpass file: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)

def create_source_conn(source_database, target_database, user, password):
    try:
        conn_query = f"""
                         select db_name, db_host, db_port \\
                         from pgctrl.db_control \\
                         where db_alias = '{source_database}'
                      """
        psql_command = f"psql -d {target_database} -U {user} -t -c \"{conn_query}\""
        #result = subprocess.run(psql_command, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        result = subprocess.run(psql_command, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

        # Verificar se a consulta retornou algum resultado
        if result.stdout.strip():
            # Extrair os dados da conexão do resultado da consulta
            source_conn = result.stdout.strip().split('|')
            # Construir a string de conexão
            connection_string = f"-h {source_conn[1].strip()} -p {source_conn[2].strip()} -d {source_conn[0].strip()} -U {user}"
            create_pgpass_file(source_conn[1].strip(), source_conn[2].strip(), source_conn[0].strip(), user, password)
        #    print(f"{connection_string}")
            return connection_string
        else:
            print(f"No entries found for {source_database}, ask dba to create it.")
            return None

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error to execute the psql command: {e}")
        return None


def read_tables_from_file(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            tables = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]
        return tables
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading tables from file: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)

def get_primary_key_column(connection_string, source_schema, table, logger):
    try:
        # Query to retrieve the primary key column name
        pk_query = f"""
            SELECT
                column_name
            FROM
                information_schema.key_column_usage
            WHERE
                table_schema = '{source_schema.lower()}'
                AND table_name = '{table.lower()}'
                AND constraint_name = (
                    SELECT constraint_name
                    FROM information_schema.table_constraints
                    WHERE table_schema = '{source_schema.lower()}'
                    AND table_name = '{table.lower()}'
                    AND constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                )
             """
        pk_command = f"psql {connection_string} -t -c \"{pk_query}\""
        #result = subprocess.run(pk_command, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        result = subprocess.run(pk_command, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

        # Extract the primary key column name
        pk_column = result.stdout.strip()
        return pk_column

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        error_output = e.stderr
        logger.error(f"Error to retrieve primary key fro table {table}: {error_output}")
        return None

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error getting primary key column for table '{table}': {e}")
        return None

def no_primary_key(source_conn_string, source_schema, table, logger):
    try:
        columns_query = f"""
            SELECT
                column_name
            FROM
                information_schema.columns
            WHERE
                table_schema = '{source_schema.lower()}'
            AND table_name = '{table.lower()}'

            """
        columns_command = f"psql {source_conn_string} -t -c \"{columns_query}\""
        #result = subprocess.run(columns_command, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        result = subprocess.run(columns_command, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

             # Extrair os nomes das colunas da saída da consulta
        columns = [column.strip() for column in result.stdout.split('\n') if column.strip()]

        formatted_columns = ", ".join(columns)

        return formatted_columns

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        error_output = e.stderr
        logger.error(f"Error to retrieve columns for {table}: {error_output}")
        return None


    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error getting columns for table '{table}': {e}")
        return None


def truncate_table(target_database, target_schema, user, table, logger):
    try:
        truncate_command = f"psql -d {target_database} -U {user} -c \"truncate table {target_schema}.{table}\" "
        #result = subprocess.run(truncate_command, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        result = subprocess.run(truncate_command, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

        if result.returncode == 0:
            logger.info(f"Table {target_schema}.{table} truncated")

            return 0
        else:
            logger.error(f"Cannot truncate table {target_schema}.{table}")
            return 1

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        error_output = e.stderr
        logger.error(f"Truncate {table}: {error_output}")
        return 1

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error executing truncate command: {e}")
        return 1


def calculate_batch_size_pl20(source_conn_string, source_schema, table, logger, num_threads):
    try:
        count_query = f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM remote2.{table} where id <> '4'"

        count_command = f"psql {source_conn_string} -t -c \"{count_query}\""

        #result = subprocess.run(count_command, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        result = subprocess.run(count_command, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)


        # Extrair o número total de registros da saída da consulta
        total_rows = int(result.stdout.strip())

        if total_rows == 0:
            #logger.info(f"Table {table} has no rows. Skipping table.")
            return 0, 0

        batch_size = math.ceil(total_rows / num_threads)

        return batch_size, 1, total_rows

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        error_output = e.stderr
        logger.error(f"Error counting rows for table {table}: {error_output}")
        return 0, 2, 0

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error counting rows for table {table}: {e}")
        return 0, 2, 0


def calculate_threads_and_batch_size(source_conn_string, source_schema, table, logger):
    try:
        # Consulta para contar o número total de registros na tabela de origem
        count_query = f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {source_schema}.{table}"

        count_command = f"psql {source_conn_string} -t -c \"{count_query}\""
        #result = subprocess.run(count_command, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        result = subprocess.run(count_command, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

        total_rows = int(result.stdout.strip())

        if total_rows == 0:
            logger.info(f"Table {table} has no rows. Skipping table.")
            return 0, 0, 0

        # Definir o número máximo de threads
        max_threads = 25

        # Calcular o número de linhas por thread
        min_rows_per_thread = 10000

        num_threads = min(max_threads, math.ceil(total_rows / min_rows_per_thread))

        # Calcular o tamanho do lote (batch size) para cada thread
        batch_size = math.ceil(total_rows / num_threads)

        return num_threads, batch_size, total_rows

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        error_output = e.stderr
        logger.error(f"Error counting rows for table {table}: {error_output}")
        return None, None, None

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error counting rows for table {table}: {e}")
        return None, None, None



def disable_autovacuum(target_database, user, target_schema, table, logger):
    try:
        # Desativar autovacuum
        subprocess.run(f"psql -d {target_database} -U {user} -c \"ALTER TABLE {target_schema}.{table} SET (autovacuum_enabled = false);\"", shell=True, check=True)
        logger.info(f"Autovacuum disable for table: {table}")

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        logger.error(f"Error to disable autovacuum: {e}")

def enable_autovacuum(target_database, user, target_schema, table, logger):
    try:
        # Desativar autovacuum
        subprocess.run(f"psql -d {target_database} -U {user} -c \"ALTER TABLE {target_schema}.{table} SET (autovacuum_enabled = true);\"", shell=True, check=True)
        logger.info(f"Autovacuum enable for table: {table}")

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        logger.error(f"Error to enable autovacuum: {e}")

def get_constraints(target_database, target_schema, table, user):
    try:
        query = f"""
        SELECT conname, pg_get_constraintdef(oid) as const_def
        FROM pg_constraint
        WHERE conrelid = '{target_schema}.{table}'::regclass
        AND contype IN ('f')
        """
        #AND contype IN ('p', 'u') #add this if you want to drop primary and unique contraints
        command = f"psql -d {target_database} -U {user} -t -c \"{query}\""
        result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        constraints = result.stdout.strip().split('\n')
        constraint_details = [constraint.split('|', 1) for constraint in constraints if constraint.strip()]
        return constraint_details
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving constraints: {e}")
        return []


def get_non_pk_indexes(target_database, target_schema, table, user):
    try:
        query = f"""
        SELECT indexname, indexdef
        FROM pg_indexes
        WHERE schemaname = '{target_schema}'
        AND tablename = '{table}'
        AND indexdef NOT LIKE 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX %'
        AND indexdef NOT LIKE '% PRIMARY KEY %'
        """
        command = f"psql -d {target_database} -U {user} -t -c \"{query}\""
        result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        indexes = result.stdout.strip().split('\n')
        index_details = [index.split('|', 1) for index in indexes if index.strip()]
        return index_details
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving non-primary key indexes: {e}")
        return []

def drop_non_pk_indexes_and_constraints(target_database, target_schema, table, user, logger):
    try:
       # indexes = get_non_pk_indexes(target_database, target_schema, table, user)
        constraints = get_constraints(target_database, target_schema, table, user)

        #for index in indexes:
        #    index_name = index[0].strip()
        #    drop_command = f"psql -d {target_database} -U {user} -c \"DROP INDEX IF EXISTS {target_schema}.{index_name}\""
        #    subprocess.run(drop_command, shell=True, check=True)
        #    logger.info(f"Dropped index {index_name} on table {table}")

        for constraint in constraints:
            constraint_name = constraint[0].strip()
            drop_command = f"psql -d {target_database} -U {user} -c \"ALTER TABLE {target_schema}.{table} DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS {constraint_name}\""
            subprocess.run(drop_command, shell=True, check=True)
            logger.info(f"Dropped constraint {constraint_name} on table {table}")

        #return indexes, constraints
        return constraints
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        logger.error(f"Error dropping constraints: {e}")
        return [], []

def recreate_indexes_and_constraints(constraints, target_database, table, user, logger):
    try:
        #for index in indexes:
        #    index_def = index[1].strip()
        #    create_command = f"psql -d {target_database} -U {user} -c \"{index_def}\""
        #    subprocess.run(create_command, shell=True, check=True)
        #    logger.info(f"Recreated index with definition: {index_def}")

        for constraint in constraints:
            const_def = constraint[1].strip()
            create_command = f"psql -d {target_database} -U {user} -c \"ALTER TABLE {target_schema}.{table} ADD {const_def}\""
            subprocess.run(create_command, shell=True, check=True)
            logger.info(f"Recreated constraint with definition: {const_def}")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        logger.error(f"Error recreating constraints: {e}")


def load_tables_in_parallel(table_chunk, source_conn_string, source_schema, user, target_database, target_schema, log_folder, pl20):
    results = []
    for table in table_chunk:
        result = load_table(source_conn_string, source_schema, user, target_database, target_schema, table, log_folder, pl20)
        results.append(result)
    return results

def load_table(source_conn_string, source_schema, user, target_database, target_schema, table, log_folder, pl20):

#source_conn_string, source_schema, target_database, target_schema, table, log_folder
    try:
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

        log_file = f"{log_folder}/{table}.log"
        status = None

        logger = logging.getLogger(table)
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        logger.propagate = False

        logger.info(f"Starting load for table {table}")
        logger.info(f"Start time: {start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}")

        #configure_session_for_loading(target_database, user, logger)
        #indexes = drop_non_pk_indexes(target_database, target_schema, table, user, logger)

        constraints = drop_non_pk_indexes_and_constraints(target_database, target_schema, table, user, logger)

        num_threads, batch_size, total_rows = calculate_threads_and_batch_size(source_conn_string, source_schema, table,logger)

        if num_threads is None or batch_size is None or total_rows is None:
           status = "Fail"
           print(f"{status} - Table {table} | LOG PATH: {log_file}")

           return status

        elif num_threads == 0 or batch_size == 0 or total_rows == 0:
            status = "Skipped"
            print(f"{status} - Table {table} | LOG PATH: {log_file}")

            return status

        # Determinar a ordem de ordenação do SELECT
        order_by_clause = "ORDER BY "
        pk_columns = get_primary_key_column(source_conn_string, source_schema, table, logger)


        if pk_columns:
            columns = [column.strip() for column in pk_columns.split('\n') if column.strip()]
            formatted_columns = ", ".join(columns)
            # Se a tabela possui chaves primárias (PKs), ordenar por elas
            order_by_clause += formatted_columns
        else:
            order_by_clause += no_primary_key(source_conn_string, source_schema, table, logger)


        result_truncate = truncate_table(target_database, target_schema, user, table, logger)

        if result_truncate == 1:
            status = "Fail"
            print(f"{status} - Table {table} | LOG PATH: {log_file}")

            return status

        disable_autovacuum(target_database, user, target_schema, table, logger)

        #threads = []
        total_inserts = 0
        insert_counts = []
        status_code = []
        exit_code = None
        select_pl20_query = ""
        pl20_offset = 0
        pl20_batch_size = 0
        tables_pl20 = ["t05021","t05019", "t05003"]

        #adding for t05003 memory overload issue
        big_tables = ["t05003"]
        #end

        if pl20.upper() == "Y" and table in tables_pl20:
            pl20_batch_size, status_check, pl20_rows = calculate_batch_size_pl20(source_conn_string, source_schema, table,logger, num_threads)

            if pl20_batch_size == 0 and status_check == 0:
                status = "Warning"
                print(f"{status} - Table {table} | LOG PATH: {log_file}")
                logger.info(f"PL20 is set as YES, perhaps table {table} is empty in pl20 schema")

                return status

            elif pl20_batch_size == 0 and status_check == 2:
                status = "Fail"
                print(f"{status} - Table {table} | LOG PATH: {log_file}")

                return status

            else:
                pl20_offset = 0
                total_rows += pl20_rows
                select_pl20_query = f" UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM remote2.{table} where id <> '4' {order_by_clause} limit {pl20_batch_size} OFFSET {pl20_offset})"

        #adding for t05003 memory overload issue
        if table.lower() in big_tables:
            threads_per_batch = 5
            num_batches = num_threads / threads_per_batch


        else:
            num_batches = 1 # all threads at once
            threads_per_batch = num_threads

        count = 0

        for batch in range(int(num_batches)):
            threads = []
        #end
            for i in range(threads_per_batch):
                current_offset = count * batch_size
                count = count + 1

                select_query = f" \"COPY ((SELECT * from {source_schema}.{table} {order_by_clause} LIMIT {batch_size} OFFSET {current_offset}) {select_pl20_query} ) TO STDOUT \" "


                read_query = f"psql {source_conn_string} -c {select_query} "
                write_query = f"psql -d {target_database} -U {user} -c \"COPY {target_schema}.{table} FROM STDIN\" "

                pl20_offset = i * pl20_batch_size

                thread = threading.Thread(target=run_load_command, args=(read_query, write_query, logger, insert_counts, status_code))
                threads.append(thread)
                thread.start()


            for thread in threads:
               thread.join()

        #recreate_indexes(indexes, target_database, user, logger)
        recreate_indexes_and_constraints(constraints, target_database, table, user, logger)
        enable_autovacuum(target_database, user, target_schema, table, logger)

        total_inserts = sum(insert_counts)
        exit_code = 1 if 1 in status_code or not status_code or 2 in status_code else 0

        end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        duration = end_time - start_time
        formatted_duration = str(duration).split('.')[0]

            #status = None

        if exit_code == 0 and total_inserts != total_rows:
            status = 'Warning'
            logger.info(f"Table {table} loaded with warning.\n")

        elif exit_code == 1:
            status = 'Fail'

            logger.info(f"Fail to load Table {table}\n")

        else:
            status = 'Success'

            logger.info(f"Table {table} loaded successfully.\n")

        logger.info(f"End time: {end_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}")
        logger.info(f"Duration: {formatted_duration}")
        logger.info(f"Total rows supposed to be inserted: {total_rows}")
        logger.info(f"Total rows inserted: {total_inserts}")

        print(f"{status} - TABLE {table} | LOG PATH: {log_file}")

        return status

    except Exception as e:

        logger.error(f"Error loading table {table}: {e}")

        print(f"Fail - TABLE {table} | LOG PATH: {log_file}")
        status = 'Fail'
        return status

def run_load_command(read_query, write_query, logger, insert_counts, status_code):
    try:
        read_process = subprocess.Popen(read_query, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        read_output, read_error = read_process.communicate()

        if read_process.returncode != 0:
            logger.error(f"Error reading data: {read_error.strip()}")
            status_code.append(2)

        write_process = subprocess.Popen(write_query, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        write_output, write_error = write_process.communicate(input=read_output)

        if write_process.returncode != 0:
            logger.error(f"Error writing data: {write_error.strip()}")
            status_code.append(2)

        else:
 
            insert_count = 0

            for line in write_output.split('\n'):
                if line.startswith('COPY'):
                    insert_count = int(line.split(' ')[-1])
                    break

            if insert_count == 0:
                status_code.append(1)

            else:
                status_code.append(0)

            logger.info(f"Number of rows inserted: {insert_count}")
            insert_counts.append(insert_count)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error running load command at run_load_command f: {e.stderr} ")
        status_code = 2

def load_tables_in_parallel(table_chunk, source_conn_string, source_schema, user, target_database, target_schema, log_folder, pl20):
    results = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
        future_to_table = {executor.submit(load_table, source_conn_string, source_schema, user, target_database, target_schema, table, log_folder, pl20): table for table in table_chunk}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_table):
            result = future.result()
            results.append(result)

    return results

def main(user, source_database, source_schema, target_database, target_schema, tables, log_folder, source_conn_string, pl20):
    #Divide tables into sublists of 20
    chunk_size = 20

    table_chunks = [tables[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(tables), chunk_size)]

    load_start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    print(f'Remote databse is {source_database}')
    print(f'Remote schema is {source_schema}')
    print(f'Local database is {target_database}')
    print(f'Local schema is {target_schema}')
    print(f'User is {user}')
    print(f"Start online_load_parallel at: {load_start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}\n")

    total_tables = len(tables)
    success_count = 0
    warning_count = 0
    fail_count = 0
    skipped_count = 0
    any_warnings_or_failures = False

    #configure_database_for_loading(target_database, user, logging.getLogger("main"))

    #with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
    for chunk in table_chunks:
        chunk_result = load_tables_in_parallel(chunk, source_conn_string, source_schema, user, target_database, target_schema, log_folder, pl20)


        for result in chunk_result:

            if result == 'Success':
                success_count += 1
            elif result == 'Warning':
                warning_count += 1
                any_warnings_or_failures = True
            elif result == 'Skipped':
                skipped_count += 1
            elif result == 'Fail':
                fail_count += 1
                any_warnings_or_failures = True

    #restore_database_configuration(target_database, user, logging.getLogger("main"))

    load_end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(f"\nEnd online_load_parallel at: {load_end_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}")
    print(f"Total tables: {total_tables}")
    print(f"Success: {success_count}")
    print(f"Warnings: {warning_count}")
    print(f"Failures: {fail_count}")
    print(f"Skipped: {skipped_count}")

    if any_warnings_or_failures:
        print("Not all tables were loaded successfully, please check the logs for more information")
        #sys.exit(1)  # Exit with non-zero code if there were warnings or failures
        exit_status = 1

    else:
        print("All tables loaded successfully.")
        #sys.exit(0)  # Exit with zero code if all tables loaded successfully
        exit_status = 0

    load_duration_time = load_end_time - load_start_time
    load_duration_formatted = str(load_duration_time).split('.')[0]

    print(f"Load duration: {load_duration_formatted}")
    sys.exit(exit_status)



if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    if len(sys.argv) != 9:
        print("Usage: python script.py source_database source_schema user password target_database target_schema tables_file pl20(Y/N)")
        sys.exit(1)

    # Parse command line arguments
    source_database = sys.argv[1]
    source_schema = sys.argv[2]
    user = sys.argv[3]
    password = sys.argv[4]
    target_database = sys.argv[5]
    target_schema = sys.argv[6]
    tables_file = sys.argv[7]
    pl20 = sys.argv[8]

    # Read tables from file
    tables = read_tables_from_file(tables_file)

   
    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_time = time.strftime("%H-%M-%S")

    log_folder = f"logs/{target_schema}/{datetime.date.today()}/{current_time}"
    os.makedirs(log_folder, exist_ok=True)

    #create_pgpass_file(host, port, database, user, password)

    source_conn_string = create_source_conn(source_database, target_database, user, password)

    main(user,  source_database, source_schema, target_database, target_schema, tables, log_folder, source_conn_string, pl20 )

    # Remove .pgpass file
    pgpass_path = os.path.expanduser("~/.pgpass")
    if os.path.exists(pgpass_path):
        os.remove(pgpass_path)


Does anyone have any idea in which would be the best way to do that?
The role process in copy the tables is because we have a lot of environments that run different kind of test, so we need to keep then up to date according on the testing being running in that environment.
If you have any idea, please let me know. I can provide more details if needed.

Why don't you copy the data using dblink or a complete foreign data wrapper? You're now using two database connections, while just one connection between the source and target should be enough.
